# PrismJs line numbers for code blocks inside an expandable div appear wrapped. Recover when zoomed in/out

Tags: syntax-highlighting, pre, line-numbers, prismjs

I am trying to add line numbers to code blocks using PrismJs Line Numbers plugin.
The code blocks are included within an expanded div as shown below:

```
<h2><a class="dropspot" data-open-text="" data-rhwidget="ExpandSpot" data-target="expanding2" href="#">Sample </a></h2>
  <div class="droptext" data-targetname="expanding2">
    <p class="Codeheadingnew">Specify the inputs to create a job</p>
    <div>
      <pre class="line-numbers">
      <code class="language-JSON">
        {
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Job with specific patches&quot;,
    &quot;description&quot;: &quot;Created via  API&quot;,
    &quot;approvches&quot;: [
        &quot;ca0d5b3a517&quot;,
        &quot;9285e676-61d84542c7bf&quot;
    ],
</code>
</pre>
    </div>
```

The CSS is here:

```
code[class*=language-],
pre[class*=language-] {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #ccc;
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre;
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  -o-tab-size: 4;
  tab-size: 4;
  -webkit-hyphens: none;
  -moz-hyphens: none;
  -ms-hyphens: none;
  hyphens: none;
  background-color: #35434D;
  max-height: 350px;
}
pre[class*=language-] {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: -0.1em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
:not(pre)>code[class*=language-],
pre[class*=language-] {
  background: #35434D;
}
:not(pre)>code[class*=language-] {
  padding: .1em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  white-space: normal;
}
/* Code style box scrollbar for Chrome and Edge */
pre[class*=language-]::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
}
pre[class*=language-]::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
pre[class*=language-]::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #898b8c;
}
.token.block-comment,
.token.cdata,
.token.comment,
.token.doctype,
.token.prolog {
  color: #999;
}
.token.punctuation {
  color: #ccc;
}
.token.attr-name,
.token.deleted,
.token.namespace,
.token.tag {
  color: #e2777a;
}
.token.function-name {
  color: #6196cc;
}
.token.boolean,
.token.function,
.token.number {
  color: #f08d49;
}
.token.class-name,
.token.constant,
.token.property,
.token.symbol {
  color: #f8c555;
}
.token.atrule,
.token.builtin,
.token.important,
.token.keyword,
.token.selector {
  color: #cc99cd;
}
.token.attr-value,
.token.char,
.token.regex,
.token.string,
.token.variable {
  color: #7ec699;
}
.token.entity,
.token.operator,
.token.url {
  color: #67cdcc;
}
.token.bold,
.token.important {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.token.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
.token.entity {
  cursor: help;
}
.token.inserted {
  color: green;
}
pre[class*=language-].line-numbers {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 3.8em;
  counter-reset: linenumber;
}
pre[class*=language-].line-numbers>code {
  position: relative;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.line-numbers .line-numbers-rows {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  left: -3.8em;
  width: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.line-numbers-rows>span {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: linenumber;
}
.line-numbers-rows>span:before {
  content: counter(linenumber);
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  padding-right: .8em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

and the JS is here:

```
var _self = "undefined" != typeof window ? window : "undefined" != typeof WorkerGlobalScope && self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope ? self : {}, Prism = function (e) { var n = /(?:^|\s)lang(?:uage)?-([\w-]+)(?=\s|$)/i, t = 0, r = {}, a = { manual: e.Prism && e.Prism.manual, disableWorkerMessageHandler: e.Prism && e.Prism.disableWorkerMessageHandler, util: { encode: function e(n) { return n instanceof i ? new i(n.type, e(n.content), n.alias) : Array.isArray(n) ? n.map(e) : n.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/\u00a0/g, " ") }, type: function (e) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(e).slice(8, -1) }, objId: function (e) { return e.__id || Object.defineProperty(e, "__id", { value: ++t }), e.__id }, clone: function e(n, t) { var r, i; switch (t = t || {}, a.util.type(n)) { case "Object": if (i = a.util.objId(n), t[i]) return t[i]; for (var l in r = {}, t[i] = r, n) n.hasOwnProperty(l) && (r[l] = e(n[l], t)); return r; case "Array": return i = a.util.objId(n), t[i] ? t[i] : (r = [], t[i] = r, n.forEach((function (n, a) { r[a] = e(n, t) })), r); default: return n } }, getLanguage: function (e) { for (; e;) { var t = n.exec(e.className); if (t) return t[1].toLowerCase(); e = e.parentElement } return "none" }, setLanguage: function (e, t) { e.className = e.className.replace(RegExp(n, "gi"), ""), e.classList.add("language-" + t) }, currentScript: function () { if ("undefined" == typeof document) return null; if ("currentScript" in document) return document.currentScript; try { throw new Error } catch (r) { var e = (/at [^(\r\n]*\((.*):[^:]+:[^:]+\)$/i.exec(r.stack) || [])[1]; if (e) { var n = document.getElementsByTagName("script"); for (var t in n) if (n[t].src == e) return n[t] } return null } }, isActive: function (e, n, t) { for (var r = "no-" + n; e;) { var a = e.classList; if (a.contains(n)) return !0; if (a.contains(r)) return !1; e = e.parentElement } return !!t } }, languages: { plain: r, plaintext: r, text: r, txt: r, extend: function (e, n) { var t = a.util.clone(a.languages[e]); for (var r in n) t[r] = n[r]; return t }, insertBefore: function (e, n, t, r) { var i = (r = r || a.languages)[e], l = {}; for (var o in i) if (i.hasOwnProperty(o)) { if (o == n) for (var s in t) t.hasOwnProperty(s) && (l[s] = t[s]); t.hasOwnProperty(o) || (l[o] = i[o]) } var u = r[e]; return r[e] = l, a.languages.DFS(a.languages, (function (n, t) { t === u && n != e && (this[n] = l) })), l }, DFS: function e(n, t, r, i) { i = i || {}; var l = a.util.objId; for (var o in n) if (n.hasOwnProperty(o)) { t.call(n, o, n[o], r || o); var s = n[o], u = a.util.type(s); "Object" !== u || i[l(s)] ? "Array" !== u || i[l(s)] || (i[l(s)] = !0, e(s, t, o, i)) : (i[l(s)] = !0, e(s, t, null, i)) } } }, plugins: {}, highlightAll: function (e, n) { a.highlightAllUnder(document, e, n) }, highlightAllUnder: function (e, n, t) { var r = { callback: t, container: e, selector: 'code[class*="language-"], [class*="language-"] code, code[class*="lang-"], [class*="lang-"] code' }; a.hooks.run("before-highlightall", r), r.elements = Array.prototype.slice.apply(r.container.querySelectorAll(r.selector)), a.hooks.run("before-all-elements-highlight", r); for (var i, l = 0; i = r.elements[l++];)a.highlightElement(i, !0 === n, r.callback) }, highlightElement: function (n, t, r) { var i = a.util.getLanguage(n), l = a.languages[i]; a.util.setLanguage(n, i); var o = n.parentElement; o && "pre" === o.nodeName.toLowerCase() && a.util.setLanguage(o, i); var s = { element: n, language: i, grammar: l, code: n.textContent }; function u(e) { s.highlightedCode = e, a.hooks.run("before-insert", s), s.element.innerHTML = s.highlightedCode, a.hooks.run("after-highlight", s), a.hooks.run("complete", s), r && r.call(s.element) } if (a.hooks.run("before-sanity-check", s), (o = s.element.parentElement) && "pre" === o.nodeName.toLowerCase() && !o.hasAttribute("tabindex") && o.setAttribute("tabindex", "0"), !s.code) return a.hooks.run("complete", s), void (r && r.call(s.element)); if (a.hooks.run("before-highlight", s), s.grammar) if (t && e.Worker) { var c = new Worker(a.filename); c.onmessage = function (e) { u(e.data) }, c.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ language: s.language, code: s.code, immediateClose: !0 })) } else u(a.highlight(s.code, s.grammar, s.language)); else u(a.util.encode(s.code)) }, highlight: function (e, n, t) { var r = { code: e, grammar: n, language: t }; if (a.hooks.run("before-tokenize", r), !r.grammar) throw new Error('The language "' + r.language + '" has no grammar.'); return r.tokens = a.tokenize(r.code, r.grammar), a.hooks.run("after-tokenize", r), i.stringify(a.util.encode(r.tokens), r.language) }, tokenize: function (e, n) { var t = n.rest; if (t) { for (var r in t) n[r] = t[r]; delete n.rest } var a = new s; return u(a, a.head, e), o(e, a, n, a.head, 0), function (e) { for (var n = [], t = e.head.next; t !== e.tail;)n.push(t.value), t = t.next; return n }(a) }, hooks: { all: {}, add: function (e, n) { var t = a.hooks.all; t[e] = t[e] || [], t[e].push(n) }, run: function (e, n) { var t = a.hooks.all[e]; if (t && t.length) for (var r, i = 0; r = t[i++];)r(n) } }, Token: i }; function i(e, n, t, r) { this.type = e, this.content = n, this.alias = t, this.length = 0 | (r || "").length } function l(e, n, t, r) { e.lastIndex = n; var a = e.exec(t); if (a && r && a[1]) { var i = a[1].length; a.index += i, a[0] = a[0].slice(i) } return a } function o(e, n, t, r, s, g) { for (var f in t) if (t.hasOwnProperty(f) && t[f]) { var h = t[f]; h = Array.isArray(h) ? h : [h]; for (var d = 0; d < h.length; ++d) { if (g && g.cause == f + "," + d) return; var v = h[d], p = v.inside, m = !!v.lookbehind, y = !!v.greedy, k = v.alias; if (y && !v.pattern.global) { var x = v.pattern.toString().match(/[imsuy]*$/)[0]; v.pattern = RegExp(v.pattern.source, x + "g") } for (var b = v.pattern || v, w = r.next, A = s; w !== n.tail && !(g && A >= g.reach); A += w.value.length, w = w.next) { var E = w.value; if (n.length > e.length) return; if (!(E instanceof i)) { var P, L = 1; if (y) { if (!(P = l(b, A, e, m)) || P.index >= e.length) break; var S = P.index, O = P.index + P[0].length, j = A; for (j += w.value.length; S >= j;)j += (w = w.next).value.length; if (A = j -= w.value.length, w.value instanceof i) continue; for (var C = w; C !== n.tail && (j < O || "string" == typeof C.value); C = C.next)L++, j += C.value.length; L--, E = e.slice(A, j), P.index -= A } else if (!(P = l(b, 0, E, m))) continue; S = P.index; var N = P[0], _ = E.slice(0, S), M = E.slice(S + N.length), W = A + E.length; g && W > g.reach && (g.reach = W); var z = w.prev; if (_ && (z = u(n, z, _), A += _.length), c(n, z, L), w = u(n, z, new i(f, p ? a.tokenize(N, p) : N, k, N)), M && u(n, w, M), L > 1) { var I = { cause: f + "," + d, reach: W }; o(e, n, t, w.prev, A, I), g && I.reach > g.reach && (g.reach = I.reach) } } } } } } function s() { var e = { value: null, prev: null, next: null }, n = { value: null, prev: e, next: null }; e.next = n, this.head = e, this.tail = n, this.length = 0 } function u(e, n, t) { var r = n.next, a = { value: t, prev: n, next: r }; return n.next = a, r.prev = a, e.length++, a } function c(e, n, t) { for (var r = n.next, a = 0; a < t && r !== e.tail; a++)r = r.next; n.next = r, r.prev = n, e.length -= a } if (e.Prism = a, i.stringify = function e(n, t) { if ("string" == typeof n) return n; if (Array.isArray(n)) { var r = ""; return n.forEach((function (n) { r += e(n, t) })), r } var i = { type: n.type, content: e(n.content, t), tag: "span", classes: ["token", n.type], attributes: {}, language: t }, l = n.alias; l && (Array.isArray(l) ? Array.prototype.push.apply(i.classes, l) : i.classes.push(l)), a.hooks.run("wrap", i); var o = ""; for (var s in i.attributes) o += " " + s + '="' + (i.attributes[s] || "").replace(/"/g, "&quot;") + '"'; return "<" + i.tag + ' class="' + i.classes.join(" ") + '"' + o + ">" + i.content + "</" + i.tag + ">" }, !e.document) return e.addEventListener ? (a.disableWorkerMessageHandler || e.addEventListener("message", (function (n) { var t = JSON.parse(n.data), r = t.language, i = t.code, l = t.immediateClose; e.postMessage(a.highlight(i, a.languages[r], r)), l && e.close() }), !1), a) : a; var g = a.util.currentScript(); function f() { a.manual || a.highlightAll() } if (g && (a.filename = g.src, g.hasAttribute("data-manual") && (a.manual = !0)), !a.manual) { var h = document.readyState; "loading" === h || "interactive" === h && g && g.defer ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f) : window.requestAnimationFrame ? window.requestAnimationFrame(f) : window.setTimeout(f, 16) } return a }(_self); "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = Prism), "undefined" != typeof global && (global.Prism = Prism);
Prism.languages.json = { property: { pattern: /(^|[^\\])"(?:\\.|[^\\"\r\n])*"(?=\s*:)/, lookbehind: !0, greedy: !0 }, string: { pattern: /(^|[^\\])"(?:\\.|[^\\"\r\n])*"(?!\s*:)/, lookbehind: !0, greedy: !0 }, comment: { pattern: /\/\/.*|\/\*[\s\S]*?(?:\*\/|$)/, greedy: !0 }, number: /-?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e[+-]?\d+)?\b/i, punctuation: /[{}[\],]/, operator: /:/, boolean: /\b(?:false|true)\b/, null: { pattern: /\bnull\b/, alias: "keyword" } }, Prism.languages.webmanifest = Prism.languages.json;
!function (n) { var e = /("|')(?:\\(?:\r\n?|\n|.)|(?!\1)[^\\\r\n])*\1/; n.languages.json5 = n.languages.extend("json", { property: [{ pattern: RegExp(e.source + "(?=\\s*:)"), greedy: !0 }, { pattern: /(?!\s)[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF](?:(?!\s)[$\w\xA0-\uFFFF])*(?=\s*:)/, alias: "unquoted" }], string: { pattern: e, greedy: !0 }, number: /[+-]?\b(?:NaN|Infinity|0x[a-fA-F\d]+)\b|[+-]?(?:\b\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\B\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+\b)?/ }) }(Prism);
Prism.languages.jsonp = Prism.languages.extend("json", { punctuation: /[{}[\]();,.]/ }), Prism.languages.insertBefore("jsonp", "punctuation", { function: /(?!\s)[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF](?:(?!\s)[$\w\xA0-\uFFFF])*(?=\s*\()/ });
!function () { if ("undefined" != typeof Prism && "undefined" != typeof document) { var e = "line-numbers", n = /\n(?!$)/g, t = Prism.plugins.lineNumbers = { getLine: function (n, t) { if ("PRE" === n.tagName && n.classList.contains(e)) { var i = n.querySelector(".line-numbers-rows"); if (i) { var r = parseInt(n.getAttribute("data-start"), 10) || 1, s = r + (i.children.length - 1); t < r && (t = r), t > s && (t = s); var l = t - r; return i.children[l] } } }, resize: function (e) { r([e]) }, assumeViewportIndependence: !0 }, i = void 0; window.addEventListener("resize", (function () { t.assumeViewportIndependence && i === window.innerWidth || (i = window.innerWidth, r(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("pre.line-numbers")))) })), Prism.hooks.add("complete", (function (t) { if (t.code) { var i = t.element, s = i.parentNode; if (s && /pre/i.test(s.nodeName) && !i.querySelector(".line-numbers-rows") && Prism.util.isActive(i, e)) { i.classList.remove(e), s.classList.add(e); var l, o = t.code.match(n), a = o ? o.length + 1 : 1, u = new Array(a + 1).join("<span></span>"); (l = document.createElement("span")).setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true"), l.className = "line-numbers-rows", l.innerHTML = u, s.hasAttribute("data-start") && (s.style.counterReset = "linenumber " + (parseInt(s.getAttribute("data-start"), 10) - 1)), t.element.appendChild(l), r([s]), Prism.hooks.run("line-numbers", t) } } })), Prism.hooks.add("line-numbers", (function (e) { e.plugins = e.plugins || {}, e.plugins.lineNumbers = !0 })) } function r(e) { if (0 != (e = e.filter((function (e) { var n, t = (n = e, n ? window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(n) : n.currentStyle || null : null)["white-space"]; return "pre-wrap" === t || "pre-line" === t }))).length) { var t = e.map((function (e) { var t = e.querySelector("code"), i = e.querySelector(".line-numbers-rows"); if (t && i) { var r = e.querySelector(".line-numbers-sizer"), s = t.textContent.split(n); r || ((r = document.createElement("span")).className = "line-numbers-sizer", t.appendChild(r)), r.innerHTML = "0", r.style.display = "block"; var l = r.getBoundingClientRect().height; return r.innerHTML = "", { element: e, lines: s, lineHeights: [], oneLinerHeight: l, sizer: r } } })).filter(Boolean); t.forEach((function (e) { var n = e.sizer, t = e.lines, i = e.lineHeights, r = e.oneLinerHeight; i[t.length - 1] = void 0, t.forEach((function (e, t) { if (e && e.length > 1) { var s = n.appendChild(document.createElement("span")); s.style.display = "block", s.textContent = e } else i[t] = r })) })), t.forEach((function (e) { for (var n = e.sizer, t = e.lineHeights, i = 0, r = 0; r < t.length; r++)void 0 === t[r] && (t[r] = n.children[i++].getBoundingClientRect().height) })), t.forEach((function (e) { var n = e.sizer, t = e.element.querySelector(".line-numbers-rows"); n.style.display = "none", n.innerHTML = "", e.lineHeights.forEach((function (e, n) { t.children[n].style.height = e + "px" })) })) } } }();
!function () { if ("undefined" != typeof Prism) { var e = Object.assign || function (e, t) { for (var n in t) t.hasOwnProperty(n) && (e[n] = t[n]); return e }, t = { "remove-trailing": "boolean", "remove-indent": "boolean", "left-trim": "boolean", "right-trim": "boolean", "break-lines": "number", indent: "number", "remove-initial-line-feed": "boolean", "tabs-to-spaces": "number", "spaces-to-tabs": "number" }; n.prototype = { setDefaults: function (t) { this.defaults = e(this.defaults, t) }, normalize: function (t, n) { for (var r in n = e(this.defaults, n)) { var i = r.replace(/-(\w)/g, (function (e, t) { return t.toUpperCase() })); "normalize" !== r && "setDefaults" !== i && n[r] && this[i] && (t = this[i].call(this, t, n[r])) } return t }, leftTrim: function (e) { return e.replace(/^\s+/, "") }, rightTrim: function (e) { return e.replace(/\s+$/, "") }, tabsToSpaces: function (e, t) { return t = 0 | t || 4, e.replace(/\t/g, new Array(++t).join(" ")) }, spacesToTabs: function (e, t) { return t = 0 | t || 4, e.replace(RegExp(" {" + t + "}", "g"), "\t") }, removeTrailing: function (e) { return e.replace(/\s*?$/gm, "") }, removeInitialLineFeed: function (e) { return e.replace(/^(?:\r?\n|\r)/, "") }, removeIndent: function (e) { var t = e.match(/^[^\S\n\r]*(?=\S)/gm); return t && t[0].length ? (t.sort((function (e, t) { return e.length - t.length })), t[0].length ? e.replace(RegExp("^" + t[0], "gm"), "") : e) : e }, indent: function (e, t) { return e.replace(/^[^\S\n\r]*(?=\S)/gm, new Array(++t).join("\t") + "$&") }, breakLines: function (e, t) { t = !0 === t ? 80 : 0 | t || 80; for (var n = e.split("\n"), i = 0; i < n.length; ++i)if (!(r(n[i]) <= t)) { for (var o = n[i].split(/(\s+)/g), a = 0, l = 0; l < o.length; ++l) { var s = r(o[l]); (a += s) > t && (o[l] = "\n" + o[l], a = s) } n[i] = o.join("") } return n.join("\n") } }, "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = n), Prism.plugins.NormalizeWhitespace = new n({ "remove-trailing": !0, "remove-indent": !0, "left-trim": !0, "right-trim": !0 }), Prism.hooks.add("before-sanity-check", (function (e) { var n = Prism.plugins.NormalizeWhitespace; if ((!e.settings || !1 !== e.settings["whitespace-normalization"]) && Prism.util.isActive(e.element, "whitespace-normalization", !0)) if (e.element && e.element.parentNode || !e.code) { var r = e.element.parentNode; if (e.code && r && "pre" === r.nodeName.toLowerCase()) { for (var i in null == e.settings && (e.settings = {}), t) if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(t, i)) { var o = t[i]; if (r.hasAttribute("data-" + i)) try { var a = JSON.parse(r.getAttribute("data-" + i) || "true"); typeof a === o && (e.settings[i] = a) } catch (e) { } } for (var l = r.childNodes, s = "", c = "", u = !1, m = 0; m < l.length; ++m) { var f = l[m]; f == e.element ? u = !0 : "#text" === f.nodeName && (u ? c += f.nodeValue : s += f.nodeValue, r.removeChild(f), --m) } if (e.element.children.length && Prism.plugins.KeepMarkup) { var d = s + e.element.innerHTML + c; e.element.innerHTML = n.normalize(d, e.settings), e.code = e.element.textContent } else e.code = s + e.code + c, e.code = n.normalize(e.code, e.settings) } } else e.code = n.normalize(e.code, e.settings) })) } function n(t) { this.defaults = e({}, t) } function r(e) { for (var t = 0, n = 0; n < e.length; ++n)e.charCodeAt(n) == "\t".charCodeAt(0) && (t += 3); return e.length + t } }();
!function () { if ("undefined" != typeof Prism && "undefined" != typeof document) { var e = [], t = {}, n = function () { }; Prism.plugins.toolbar = {}; var a = Prism.plugins.toolbar.registerButton = function (n, a) { var r; r = "function" == typeof a ? a : function (e) { var t; return "function" == typeof a.onClick ? ((t = document.createElement("button")).type = "button", t.addEventListener("click", (function () { a.onClick.call(this, e) }))) : "string" == typeof a.url ? (t = document.createElement("a")).href = a.url : t = document.createElement("span"), a.className && t.classList.add(a.className), t.textContent = a.text, t }, n in t ? console.warn('There is a button with the key "' + n + '" registered already.') : e.push(t[n] = r) }, r = Prism.plugins.toolbar.hook = function (a) { var r = a.element.parentNode; if (r && /pre/i.test(r.nodeName) && !r.parentNode.classList.contains("code-toolbar")) { var o = document.createElement("div"); o.classList.add("code-toolbar"), r.parentNode.insertBefore(o, r), o.appendChild(r); var i = document.createElement("div"); i.classList.add("toolbar"); var l = e, d = function (e) { for (; e;) { var t = e.getAttribute("data-toolbar-order"); if (null != t) return (t = t.trim()).length ? t.split(/\s*,\s*/g) : []; e = e.parentElement } }(a.element); d && (l = d.map((function (e) { return t[e] || n }))), l.forEach((function (e) { var t = e(a); if (t) { var n = document.createElement("div"); n.classList.add("toolbar-item"), n.appendChild(t), i.appendChild(n) } })), o.appendChild(i) } }; a("label", (function (e) { var t = e.element.parentNode; if (t && /pre/i.test(t.nodeName) && t.hasAttribute("data-label")) { var n, a, r = t.getAttribute("data-label"); try { a = document.querySelector("template#" + r) } catch (e) { } return a ? n = a.content : (t.hasAttribute("data-url") ? (n = document.createElement("a")).href = t.getAttribute("data-url") : n = document.createElement("span"), n.textContent = r), n } })), Prism.hooks.add("complete", r) } }();
!function () { function t(t) { var e = document.createElement("textarea"); e.value = t.getText(), e.style.top = "0", e.style.left = "0", e.style.position = "fixed", document.body.appendChild(e), e.focus(), e.select(); try { var o = document.execCommand("copy"); setTimeout((function () { o ? t.success() : t.error() }), 1) } catch (e) { setTimeout((function () { t.error(e) }), 1) } document.body.removeChild(e) } "undefined" != typeof Prism && "undefined" != typeof document && (Prism.plugins.toolbar ? Prism.plugins.toolbar.registerButton("copy-to-clipboard", (function (e) { var o = e.element, n = function (t) { var e = { copy: "Copy", "copy-error": "Press Ctrl+C to copy", "copy-success": "Copied!", "copy-timeout": 5e3 }; for (var o in e) { for (var n = "data-Prismjs-" + o, c = t; c && !c.hasAttribute(n);)c = c.parentElement; c && (e[o] = c.getAttribute(n)) } return e }(o), c = document.createElement("button"); c.className = "copy-to-clipboard-button", c.setAttribute("type", "button"); var r = document.createElement("span"); return c.appendChild(r), u("copy"), function (e, o) { e.addEventListener("click", (function () { !function (e) { navigator.clipboard ? navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.getText()).then(e.success, (function () { t(e) })) : t(e) }(o) })) }(c, { getText: function () { return o.textContent }, success: function () { u("copy-success"), i() }, error: function () { u("copy-error"), setTimeout((function () { !function (t) { window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(t) }(o) }), 1), i() } }), c; function i() { setTimeout((function () { u("copy") }), n["copy-timeout"]) } function u(t) { r.textContent = n[t], c.setAttribute("data-copy-state", t) } })) : console.warn("Copy to Clipboard plugin loaded before Toolbar plugin.")) }();
```

When published the line numbers appear wrapped into a single number as shown below:
[Line numbers appear wrapped up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGI5B.png)

When zooming in or out, the line numbers appear good.
[Line numbers appear ok when zooming in or out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXblj.png)

When the same code block is added outside the expander, the line numbers appear correctly.

What could be the issue?